# Android studio error upgrading gradle from v3.4.1 to v6+

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to update my gradle from 3.4.1 to 6.1.1 and after sync project i get the error: "No value has been specifed for this property". But for what property i dont know.

I was trying to run the comand "gradlew --warning-mode all". I got the message that im using deprecated name such as "archiveFile", i replaced it with "archiveFileName" but it gave me the same results.

I also disable/enable checkbox "Only sync the active variant" in File > Settings > Experimental with no luck.

I know that error may appear when some libraries implementations are too old for current gradle verison 6.1.1. But how can i know which library version is no longer supported ? Or im doing something wrong ?

[image: Gradle upgrade error]

Comment: please share file build.gradle

Comment: invalidate the catches and restart the android studio